# Are there any DbContext equivalents to DataContext CreateDatabase and DeleteDatabase?

Tags: .net, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I have used these methods to quickly bootstrap a database on a new Entity Framework project:

- [`DataContext.CreateDatabase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.createdatabase.aspx)
- [`DataContext.DeleteDatabase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.deletedatabase.aspx)
- [`DataContext.DatabaseExists`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.databaseexists.aspx)

Is there similar functionality I can use with a DbContext?  It seems those methods were not moved over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Database` property of the DbContext (see `System.Data.Entity.Database`) exposes the following methods:

- Create()
- CreateIfNotExists()
- Exists()

Here's the link to the MSDN documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database(v=VS.103).aspx

Comment: Oh - Thanks!  I've read that the purpose of the `DbContext` was to move things off the base classes and into properties.  I should have check this first :)